# Segmentation Fault declaring class private variable

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to call a class function in my program.  During my program, the matrix `grid[][]` changes rapidly, and I want to be able to at a certain time save an "image" of the grid, so that I can compare later versions of the grid to this reference.  So when I try to save the "image" of `grid[][]` to the reference matrix, I simply copy all of the values to it using a for loop.  I did a couple tests during my program and I seem to be getting a segmentation fault during the `getreference` function.

```
class lattice
{
public:
    lattice(){} // Constructor
    ~lattice(){} // Destructor
    void getgrid(){...}

    //Other functions...

    void getreference()
  {
    for(int a = 0; a<SIZEX; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; a<SIZEY; b++)
        {
            reference[a][b] = grid[a][b];
        }
    }
  }

private:
    short grid[SIZEX][SIZEY];
    short reference[SIZEX][SIZEY];
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop's condition is wrong.

Comment: For future reference, the first thing you should do in a case like this is add the obvious `assert` checks for conditions that you know can cause a fault. For example, adding `assert((a >= 0) && (a < SIZEX) && (b >= 0) && (b < SIZEY));` would have caught this. Also, you could have used [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int b = 0; a < SIZEY; b++)
```

should be

```
for(int b = 0; b < SIZEY; b++)
```

That's why you got a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(int a = 0; a<SIZEX; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; a<SIZEY; b++) //??
        {
            reference[a][b] = grid[a][b];
        }
    }
```

change it to `for(int b = 0; b < SIZEY; b++)`